# CImageHelper::Init () Failed load of symbol file with path =

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Recently I have noticed that following error started to be logged :
CImageHelper::Init () Failed load of symbol file with path = ...\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn;...\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\BINN Error Code 0xc0000004

Error occurs once per day at the same time.
There is no dump which follows this error, I have found no relevant information in Windows Logs.

SQL Server version is 2016 SP2.

Thankyou in advance for help.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219555/error-cimagehelperinit-failed-load-of-symbol-file-with-path

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34032724-ceip-service-cause-noisy-error-log

Comment: Thank you for the links, I have read them, but I am not convinced to modify ini files.